# how to input Ctrl-D

Tags: bash

My question is no need to show code. When I try to run my script on Linux terminal that takes <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> as one of the arguments. However, once I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the terminal logout. How can I type it in a correct way?

Comment: How does it take Ctrl-D "as an argument"? Typically, you can enter an escape sequence with Ctrl-V, so in your case Ctrl-V Ctrl-D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Linux results in the operating system sends an 'EOF' signal to the program. In order to input <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you need to tell the operating system to see it as normal input. To do that, you can type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> first, and then type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: @SmAc glad that I can help